# Django tables get generated with domain\username prefixed before table name

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am using Microsoft SQL server with Django (1.8.4). When I run migrations, the tables get created as

```
domain\username.table_name1
domain\username.table_name2
```

instead of

```
table_name1
table_name2
```

How do I resolve this? Is there a configuration for the naming format?

Django is running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work: In model class's meta, add an attribute, `db_table = 'table_name1'` and then run `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Check here for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, so you could have similar models in multiple applications. Otherwise, two application might use an "Expenses" or "Songs" model, and the DB will fail to create two tables with the same name.

You should usually stick with the default naming scheme.

The db_table Meta option does let you specify the table name, but it is mostly for existing legacy database.

Comment: I understand why it prefixes app name. But here it prefixes username. like EU/johna.app_tablename

Comment: I suspect it's a Microsoft SQL thing. Migrations operations create table based on app label and model name. The migration is generic, and then django has a "SchemaEditor" for each DB. Couldn't see where MS-SQL is, though, https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/backends

Answer (score 0):

Alter user's default schema you are connecting with. 
When you create a user and allow it to access a database, server create a schema of the same name and sets it as user's default schema. If you did not set one explicitly.

Django does not work with schemas and does not try to create "dbo.MyTable" - it attempts to create "MyTable" and finally it goes to the default schema which is your username.